# Python best practice secrets for azure functions and other scripts

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, secret-key

I have a python project which contains an azure function and other scripts. The project structure is as follows:

```
__app__ 
 | - myAzureFunction
 | | - __init__.py
 | | - function.json
 | | - example.py
 | - scripts
 | | - myFirstScript.py
 | | - mySecondScript.py
 | - host.json 
 | - local.settings.json
 | - requirements.txt
```

During develeopment, I created the scripts first. They are accessing data from a blob storage. I stored all the secrets as environment variables. Now I have added an azure function and that requires the secrets to be stored in local.settings.json. Having them stored twice - as environment variables and in local.settings.json does not seem right to me. Is there a best practice for doing this?

I tried

```
import os 
settings = os.environment["someKey"]
```

which works in myAzureFunction/**init**.py, but not in scripts/myFirstScript.py.

I am aware of this solution https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-python?tabs=cmd but that implies still two approaches: one for simple scripts and one for azure functions. I thought there might be a single uniform approach.

Comment: Hi, any update?

Answer (score 0):

> During develeopment, I created the scripts first. They are accessing
> data from a blob storage. I stored all the secrets as environment
> variables. Now I have added an azure function and that requires the
> secrets to be stored in local.settings.json. Having them stored twice
>
> - as environment variables and in local.settings.json does not seem right to me. Is there a best practice for doing this?

When function starts, it reads section named 'Values' from local.settings.json or reads values from the configuration settings of function app. This is limited to azure function. When the function terminates, the environment variables read in the memory space will be cleared. Therefore, if you don't put function and your script in a hierarchical relationship, then they cannot use the same environment variables.

So, you have two ways:

1, Set the environment variable in the machine level.

Because your function app and python script are both located inside a certain computer (may be an actual computer or a virtual machine), you can set the environment variable of the upper machine so that they can all get this value.

2, import scripts/myFirstScript.py as module.

like below:

**`myFirstScript.py`**

```
import os
def some_func():
    print(os.getenv('FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME'))
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # test1.py executed as script
    # do something
    some_func()
```

**`myAzureFunction/__init__.py`**

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func
from ..scripts import myFirstScript

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
        
    myFirstScript.some_func()

    return func.HttpResponse(
            "This is a test.",
            status_code=200
    )
```

I suggest using a similar method to the second method, using function as the parent of your python script, so that you can share temporary environment variables in memory.

Comment: Thank you! I used the first method and intended to leave the local.settings.json entirely empty. However every time I locally run the azure function, AzureWebJobsStorage key and its value are automatically set. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @Vicky Most azure functions are mandatory to fill AzureWebJobsStorage key and its value in local.settings.json when running locally. (Except for httptrigger) There seems to be no good way to do this locally. The bottom layer of the function is designed like this. . . (Although I don't know why it is designed this way) I think you need to provide this value in the configuration file, otherwise your function app will not run at all.